# Validación de inicio de sesión personalizada en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

En este momento tengo un formulario de inicio de sesión que valida correo electrónico y contraseña.

Adicional a esto en la tabla de `users` tengo un campo de compañía, campo que se solicita en el formulario de inicio. Hasta ahí todo va bien pero sucede que si yo dígito correctamente el correo y la contraseña aunque seleccione una compañía diferente a la que tiene el registro en la tabla el sistema permite entrar.

¿Cómo puedo hacer una validación personalizada (creo que en `AtheticateUsers`) para no dejar que entre al sistema si no selecciona la compañía correcta?

Answer (score 2):

Respondiento mi propia pregunta lo logré de la siguiente manera editando el archivo `AuthenticateUsers`, simplemente agregando el campo de la tabla después de `password`.

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password', 'Compania_idCompania');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En attempt puedes especificar que campos utilizarás en la validación de inicio de sesión, como **email y password** (siempre necesarios), y otras condiciones, como el id de la compañia que envies desde `<select>`. Suponiendo que ésta sea **CompanyId** el resultado sería el siguiente:

```
Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email,'password' => $pass,'CompanyId'=>$companyid), $remember));
```

Esto se describe en la [documentación de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#authenticating-users), en este caso la versión 5.0.